# Poison Qb2 and prerequisites for Vaganian

Tags: caro-kann, 1.d4, london-system, poisoned-pawn

[What does black achieve with 1.d4 c6?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/what-does-black-achieve-with-1-d4-c6)

Contributor mentions 1. d4 c6 2. Bf4 Qb6.  Database shows few such openings, all responding 3.b3 with *white winning no matches*.  Should white offer Qxb2 poison?  Can white follow with Vaganian Gambit given Nb5 is no threat.  Without Nb5, can white still trap the Q?

Answer (score 2):

Computer variants (Lichess/Stockfish) are no answer ;-), but since it would get way too long for a comment...

1.d4 c6 (Playable, +0.3 vs e.g. +0.2 for d5, but very tame.) 2.Bf4 (Also uncommon, back to +0.1 vs. a normal developing move.) 2...Qb6 (Back to +0.3, again a normal move like Nf6 is preferrable) 3.Nf3 (+0.3, b3 is only +0.1) 3...Qxb2 (Asking for it, +0.9.) After the following, say, 4.Nbd2 d5 5.e4 White has a scary development advantage which, as the computer assessment shows, compensates for the pawn big time. On the other hand, White must play energically to justify it, since +0.9 also means Black is not immediately busted and might defend to "teeth's skin" and bring home the bacon resp. pawn in the endgame, as *my* typical games go...